# Is it possible to match encrypted documents using user-defined search terms?

Tags: encryption, searchable-encryption, secure-index

Suppose I am storing a number of encrypted documents in a database. I would like to make it possible to identify the subset of documents whose contents match user-specified search terms without a) maintaining a plaintext index or b) decrypting documents on the fly. Is there any way to accomplish this securely?

By the same token, I'm wondering if a collection of encrypted documents can be sorted according to an encrypted attribute (e.g., document title) without first decrypting all attribute values.

Comment: this might be the answer I'm looking for: http://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/secureindex/secureindex.pdf

Comment: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mariana/papers/sads_ccsw.pdf might be worth looking at too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  If you encrypt the documents with this purpose in mind (you have to use a special kind of encryption algorithm), then yes, it is possible to do this, for certain kinds of search queries.

There is a rich research literature on this topic.  The buzzword is "search on encrypted data".  I'll point you to a few sample papers in this space.  Do a literature search, and you should be able to find many more for yourself.

- [CryptDB: Protecting Confidentiality with Encrypted Query Processing](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/raluca-cryptdb.pdf), Raluca Ada Popa, Catherine M. S. Redfield, Nickolai Zeldovich, and Hari Balakrishnan.  SOSP 2011.  See also [the CryptDB web page](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/).
- [Secure Indexes](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/secureindex/secureindex.pdf), Eu-Jin Goh.
- [Practical Techniques for Searches on Encrypted Data](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~dawnsong/papers/se.pdf), Dawn Xiaodong Song, David Wagner, and Adrian Perrig.  IEEE Security & Privacy 2000.
- [Public key encryption with keyword search](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/encsearch.pdf), Dan Boneh, Giovanni Di Crescenzo, Rafail Ostrovsky, Giuseppe Persiano. EUROCRYPT 2004.
- [Designing Secure Indexes for Encrypted Databases](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~ronen/Site/Research_files/Secure%20Indexes.pdf), Erez Shmueli, Ronen Waisenberg, Yuval Elovici, and Ehud Gudes. Database Security 2005.
- [How to Search on Encrypted Data](http://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eeujin/papers/secureindex/2003nov-encsearch.pdf), Eu-Jin Goh.  Slides.
- [Private Searching On Streaming Data](http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/242.pdf), Rafail Ostrovsky and William E. Skeith III.  CRYPTO 2005.
- [New Constructions and Applications for Private Stream Search (Extended Abstract)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Edawnsong/papers/stream-search.pdf), John Bethencourt, Dawn Song, and Brent Waters.  IEEE Security & Privacy 2006.
- [Secure Ranked Keyword Search over Encrypted Cloud Data](http://www.ece.iit.edu/~ubisec/cloud/papers/ICDCS10-search.pdf), Cong Wang, Ning Cao, Jin Li, Kui Ren, and Wenjing Lou.  ICDCS 2010.
- [Enabling Efficient Fuzzy Keyword Search over Encrypted Data in Cloud Computing](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/593.pdf), Jin Li, Qian Wang, Cong Wang, Ning Cao, Kui Ren, and Wenjing Lou.
- [New Security Models and Provably-Secure Schemes for Basic Query Support in Outsourced Databases](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~aboldyre/papers/abo.pdf) Amanatidis, Boldyreva, O'Neill. 2007
- [Privacy Preserving Keyword Searches on Remote Encrypted Data](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/acns2005.pdf) Chang and Mitzenmacher. 2005
- [Highly-Scalable Searchable Symmetric Encryption with Support for Boolean Queries](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/169.pdf) Cash et al. in CRYPTO 2013
- [Multi-key Searchable Encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/508.pdf) Popa and Zeldovich. 2013.
- [Searchable Symmetric Encryption: Improved Definitions and Efficient Constructions](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/210.pdf) Curtmola et al. 2006

The best scheme for your situation will depend upon your application requirements.  If you have a read-mostly database (updates are rarer than searches), then I would suggest a scheme based upon encrypted indexes.  If you need to make modifications frequently, or if searching is relatively rare, the other schemes might be preferable.

Comment: I'll put this in a comment because it's not directly related: 'Structured Encryption and Controlled Disclosure' Chase and Kamara 2011